# How to iterate through file line by line?

Tags: python-2.7, iterator, iteration, bioinformatics

I have files with lines of input which I compare to eachother. I have simplified my code alot and obviously it isnt in working python but the main bits of important are the first line for iteration and the else clause, both of which are the ones used. The rest are just to show I wish to continue on with the data if it passes the Comparison code.

```
for read1, read2 in itertools.izip(input_file1, input_file2):  
    {CODE FOR COMPARISON}
    if matched:
        Worked = read1+read2
    else:
        print to output_file2
        break
    {CONTINUE ANALYSIS OF 'Worked'}
    print Worked to output_file1
```

I assumed adding a print to file and break would solve the issue however it doesn't break the for loop so the next iteration occurs, it just breaks it. Is there anyway to use a command like break to move onto the next iteration of lines in both input files?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, working example](http://sscce.org) that other people can run to duplicate the issue. Also, ["a lot is two words"](http://overcompensating.com/oc/index.php?comic=272).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to use a command like break to move onto the next iteration of lines in both input files?

You are looking for the `continue` statement rather than the `break` statement:

`break` exits the loop whereas `continue` just moves onto the next iteration

```
for read1, read2 in itertools.izip(input_file1, input_file2):  
    {CODE FOR COMPARISON}
    if matched:
        Worked = read1+read2
    else:
        print to output_file2
        continue
    {CONTINUE ANALYSIS OF 'Worked'}
    print Worked to output_file1
```

See
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops